# winhttp.dll a standard windows file?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-vista, windows-xp

is **WinHttp.dll** a standard Windows file? My application depends on it, but i'd rather not deploy it in my application setup, unless it is neccessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273(v=vs.85).aspx
WinHTTP 5.1 offers improvements over version 5.0. It is included in the operating system